# Box-shadow over next sibling div

Tags: html, css

I have a box shadow on a div that i want to stick out like a bar over the next div on the page, but when the next div has a background or background image, it won't show up. is there a way of the shadow showing over the next element even though they are both "position:initial;"
http://jsfiddle.net/2u4Lvyn0/2/ 
so the shadow should overlook the blue box below it

HMTL

```
<div class="background-image-div"></div>
<div class="box-shadow-div"></div>
<div class="background-image-div"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box-shadow-div{
    height:100px;
    background:orange;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.background-image-div{
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

I've seen a lot of posts on 'inset box-shadow' not working with it's own divs background image but couldn't find anything about just regular sibling divs.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2u4Lvyn0/4/?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Adding `position:relative;` will fix it.  Though, it may affect other CSS tweaks you already have.

http://jsfiddle.net/2u4Lvyn0/5/

Comment: Also, I needed to change my z-index to get the right results.

Comment: Can you add an explanation why this answer will fix the issue?

Comment: An element with `relative` position creates a new stacking context. You can then use `z-index` to control the stack level.

Answer (score 2):

Purest way to create a new stacking context would be to use css property
`isolation: isolate;`

https://jsfiddle.net/mgfyz1j9/2/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation