# Box-shadow and sibling element with background

Tags: css

I had a problem with setting `box-shadow` over the element that has a sibling with background, almost identical to [Box-shadow over next sibling div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276634)

Solution with `position: relative` and `z-index` worked but I don't understand why. Could someone please explain?

```css
#all {
  width: 200px;
}

#header {
  background-color: white;
  height:20px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px red;
  position: relative;
}

#body { 
  height:100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
<div id="header">
header
</div>
<div id="body">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: z-index made one sibling element over another, so it shows first and that's why it has box-shadow, without z-index, all elements are next to each other and you can't see box-shadow. I think this answers your question, if I understood it properly.

Comment: @НиколаТошић, it is not only about the z-index because z-index alone wasn't a solution. However linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694564 is an answer.